# Flutter, instalar APK en dispositivo movil

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Estoy intentando generar una APK de una app movil que he hecho en flutter. He usado diferentes comandos como:

```
flutter build apk
flutter build apk --profile
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

Cada uno me ha generado un *.apk diferente, en la ruta `build\app\outputs\apk\release` me he pasado ese archivo al movil pero cuando lo abro solo me deja abrirlo con el gestor de archivos, dentro puedo ver todas las dependencias, pero no hay ningun archivo APK, ni nada que pueda instalar.

¿Alguna solución? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

El comando que debes usar es simplemente :

```
flutter install
```

Debes realizar los 3 pasos que indica la documentación:

• Conecta el dispositivo Android a tu computadora con un cable USB. Aquí es importante verificar que el clable funcione correctamente ya que en ocasiones el problema es el cable.

• Ingresar a directorio donde se tiene la aplicación, cd  donde  es el directorio de su aplicación. Ejemplo:

```
cd C:\Users\jorgesys\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp
```

• Ejecute flutter install. Dentro del directorio de tu proyecto ejecuta el comando:

```
flutter install
```

este comando instalaría el .apk en tu dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

También puede utilizar los siguientes comandos teniendo su dispositivo móvil conectado a su equipo de cómputo :

```
flutter run
```

*instala el apk en su móvil y muestra la consola de depuración(debe de dejar su dispositivo conectado para ver la consola de depuración)

```
flutter run --release
```

*instala una apk más ligera como la que usted subiría a la playStore o AppStore, una vez instalada puede desconectar su dispositivo(esta opción no muestra la consola de depuración)